# Convert Python program into C shell command script

Tags: python, unix

I have written a Python program say:

```
inp = raw_input("ENTER path ")
f = glob.iglob(os.path.join(path,'*.txt'))
for filename in f:
    if filename == 'xnak.txt': 
       print "this is a valid file"  
    else:  
       print 'not recognized'`
```

Now I want to make it a Unix C shell(csh) command with script-name `name`.

Please help me out. I don't have a high level understanding in Unix, basic and simple ideas are welcome.

Simply I just want to make this prog named `x.py` like the `cd` command in a csh. You know, wherever you type `cd [dirname]` the `cd` function works fine.  I need to just make the prog like that.
So that, I won't need to copying around the program/script from folder to folder for analyzing data of a folder.

like when in a folder I type `x 11` (and hit enter) then the program starts executing and stops after executing 11 loops of searching.
If anyone still don't understand the question properly then please ask for justification rather than downvoting or wrong answering.

Comment: hey! all the downvoters please leave an answer before just clicking.

Comment: cd works that way was because it is a shell builtin. like others said, putting your script into PATH is the only way to do what you want. see Edward Loper's comment... in order to make it behave like a shell builtin, you would have to modify the shell itself... which I doubt you would be capable of (considering you don't have a really good grasp on Unix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your python script to be executable from the shell in unix, you'll want to do two things:

1. Add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line that says it should be run using python.  This should be the first line of your script, and will probably be something like:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   ```
2. Mark the file as executable, using `chmod`.  You can do this from the command-line by typing:

   ```
   chmod +x test
   ```

Comment: @Loper what are you trying to do? i wanted to make the prog work like as the command 'cd' works in a csh. i.e. enter into a directory and type the command and you get its work. no need to copying around the prog script file to the working folders. but how??

Comment: @abhisek If I'm understanding you correctly, then you are asking how to ensure that you can run the script no matter what directory you're in.  If that's correct, then you need to ensure that the script is in a directory that's in your shell's PATH.  See the following for more information about csh command paths, including instructions for adding a new directory to your path: <http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/searchpath.html>

Comment: this is dead url you have provided...

Comment: Sorry that should be: http://washington.edu/computing/unix/searchpath.html -- The "<...>" was just being used to quote the URL (I'm surprised that StackOverflow included it in the link).

Comment: no! itz not the thing I wanted. read the question carefully. your understanding is partly correct. i want to make my prog a builtin like 'cd'.

Comment: Well, the `cd` command is handled internally by csh itself -- so if you *really* want something that's identically handled, then the only way to do that would be to modify csh's own source code, and compile your own version.  I doubt that's what you want, though.  The only other two options you have are to make an executable (or executable script) and add it to your path (i.e., the solution I suggested), or create an alias (i.e., the solution kingsindian suggested).

Answer (score 1):

Just create an alias which you can use it a unix command:

Say your python file is `test.py`. So, you do:

```
$alias name="python test.py"
```

Now, you can use `name` to execute the python script as if `name` was a command.

```
$name
```

If you want to make this work everytime you use login then give fullpath to the python script and keep in somewhere on the system and add the `alias` part to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file.

Comment: not working for me and also I have not asked this for..understand the question please before answer..